# Price extraction from Amazon Product Page is unsuccessful

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am writing a code which should extract the price from below link

URL is : `https://www.amazon.in/Sensodyne-Sensitive-Toothpaste-Repair-Protect/dp/B01AAE8JHQ/`

Code : python beautiful soup

```
price = soup.find("span", attrs={'class': 'a-size-medium a-color-price'}).string.replace('₹', '').replace(',', '.').strip()
```

this return `235.00` instead of `Rs. 188.00`

the html element from where price should be returned is as follows:

```
span class="a-size-medium a-color-price">₹188.00</span>
```

I have tried multiple variations of request, but none of them have worked. Can someone help?

Comment: The price shown is 235 rupees on amazon. Doesn't seem like a code error to me

Comment: the price on web page of this is rs.188.00
the 235 that you see is non discounted price

Comment: The discount is shown in a separated html element, make sure that you are checking the value of the right elem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not looking where you think you should be looking.

`soup.find` returns only a single matching element. See these [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

If you were to use `soup.find_all` you will also see that you will get mutliple spans back and again none of them are the value you are looking for.

You are using the incorrect class identifier (based on the default page that loads) to find the value you are looking for.